# Getting all the time: Invalid property of bean class: Bean property is not readable

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I always get this error, nonetheless whether I create the getter/setter manually or doing it via Lombok.

So, I guess the error has nothing to do with the Getters/Setters but I cannot find the answer to my problem.

This is my error message:

```
Invalid property 'person' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'person' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

This is my Enttiy class:

```
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="incomeoutgo", schema = "public")
public class IncomeOutgo extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

@Version
@NotNull
@Column(name ="id")
private Long id;

@Column(name="dayofweek")
private Date dayofweek;

@Column(name="location")
private String location;

@Size(min = 5, max = 50)
@Column(name ="person")
private String person;

@Min(0)
@Column(name ="version")
private Integer version;

@Column(name="income")
private int income;

@Column(name="outgo")
private int outgo;
}
```

And this is my Controller class

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/incomeoutgo")
public class IncomeOutgoController {

private static final String INCOMEOUTGO_VIEW = "incomeoutgo";
private final IncomOutgoService incomeoutgoService;

@GetMapping
public String showShop(Model model) {
    List<IncomeOutgo> incomeOutgoList = incomeoutgoService.getIncomeOutgoList();
    model.addAttribute(INCOMEOUTGO_VIEW, incomeOutgoList);
    return INCOMEOUTGO_VIEW;
}

@PostMapping("/incomeoutgo")
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("incomeoutgo") IncomeOutgo incomeoutgo, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    incomeoutgoService.addIncomeOutgo(incomeoutgo);
    return "incomeoutgo";
}
}
```

And last but not least my Thymeleaf template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Incomes / Expenses</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Day of Week</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Income</th>
        <th>Expense</th>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="incomeoutgo : ${incomeoutgo}">
        <td th:text="${incomeoutgo.id}">id</td>
        <td th:text="${incomeoutgo.dayofweek}">dayofweek</td>
        <td th:text="${incomeoutgo.person}">person</td>
        <td th:text="${incomeoutgo.location}">location</td>
        <td th:text="${#numbers.formatCurrency(incomeoutgo.income)}">"${#numbers.formatCurrency(incomeoutgo.income)}"</td>
        <td th:text="${#numbers.formatCurrency(incomeoutgo.outgo)}">"${#numbers.formatCurrency(incomeoutgo.outgo)}"</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<form action="#" th:action="@{/incomeoutgo}" th:object="${incomeoutgo}" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{person}" /></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('person')}" th:errors="*{person}">Name Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is explained: `Invalid property 'person' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]`.  You're trying to call `getPerson()` on a `java.util.ArrayList` (which doesn't have that property).  I suspect it's in your form:

```
<form ... th:object="${incomeoutgo}">
```

You've added `incomeoutgo` to your model as a `List<IncomeOutgo>`, but you're trying to treat it as an `IncomeOutgo` instead.  You need to create a single object and use that instead when trying to bind form field values.

```
model.addAttribute(INCOMEOUTGO_VIEW, incomeOutgoList);
model.addAttribute("page", new IncomeOutgo());

.
.
.

<form ... th:object="${page}">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{person}" />
```

(Side node, reusing the same variable name multiple times makes the code confusing.  You have the model attribute `${incomeoutgo}`, the temporary loop variable `th:each="incomeoutgo : ${incomeoutgo}"` and the bound thymeleaf object `th:object="${incomeoutgo}"` which may or may not be related.)

Comment: I tried it as you suggested but @PostMapping will never be entered in my controller.

I try to have a \@GetMapping and \@PostMapping within  one controller.

So does my HTML outputtable look (that works)

    <tr th:each="incomeoutgo : ${incomeoutgo}">
        <td th:text="${incomeoutgo.id}">id</td>
        <td th:text="${incomeoutgo.dayofweek}">dayofweek</td>
        <td th:text="${incomeoutgo.person}">person</td>
        <td th:text="${incomeoutgo.location}">location</td>
other fields omitted
    </tr>

Comment: So does my form look like

<form th:object="${page}">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Id:<input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>DayOfWeek:<input type="text" th:field="*{dayofweek}" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Name:<input type="text" th:field="*{person}" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Location:<input type="text" th:field="*{location}" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Income:<input type="text" th:field="*{income}" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Outgo:<input type="text" th:field="*{outgo}" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td></tr>

Comment: \@RequiredArgsConstructor
\@Controller
\@RequestMapping(value = "/incomeoutgo")
public class IncomeOutgoController {
\@GetMapping
public String showIncome(Model model) {
List<IncomeOutgo> incomeOutgoList = incomeoutgoService.getIncomeOutgoList();
model.addAttribute(INCOMEOUTGO_VIEW, incomeOutgoList);
model.addAttribute("page", new IncomeOutgo());
return "incomeoutgo";
}
\@PostMapping("incomeoutgo")
public String addUser(\@ModelAttribute("page") IncomeOutgo incomeoutgo, BindingResult bindingResult) {
incomeoutgoService.addIncomeOutgo(incomeoutgo);
return "incomeoutgo";
}

Comment: Sorry, but all the methods and so did not fit into one comment.

All the table fields are not null, and id is auto_increment in database table.

Comment: You have to keep everything else on your form tag.  I was just showing you how to update it to `page`.  The complete form tag will look like: `<form action="#" th:action="@{/incomeoutgo}" th:object="${page}" method="post">`.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far!

I changed it back to this version and now I get:

There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported

<form action="#" th:action="@{/incomeoutgo}" th:object="${page}" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{person}" /></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('person')}" th:errors="*{person}">Name Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
 </tr></table>
</form>

Comment: So, found the error now (hope so :))

I had to change the Annotation for my post in my controller

    @PostMapping
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("incomeoutgo") IncomeOutgo incomeoutgo, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        incomeoutgoService.addIncomeOutgo(incomeoutgo);
        return INCOMEOUTGO_VIEW;
    }